# How to compare a single number with a range of numbers in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Following sample query will return a ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

```
select product.id from product
where product.price >= (select deals.price from deals where deals.dDate >= sysdate-10)
```

Is there something in SQL to compare a single number (product price in this case) with a range of numbers (deal prices in this case)?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you want to compare them? Greater than all of them? Greater than any of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `any` or `all`, depending on the logic you want:

```
select product.id
from product
where product.price >= all (select deals.price from deals where deals.dDate >= sysdate-10);
```

Or `min()` or `max()`, depending on the logic you want:

```
select product.id
from product
where product.price >= (select max(deals.price) from deals where deals.dDate >= sysdate-10);
```

I prefer the latter.

Comment: The latter solution is better. The subquery returns just 1 row and the outer query compares against that 1 row. In the former statement, the subquery returns multiple rows and the outer query must compare against all. The 2nd will be more efficient.

Comment: @SSteven - perhaps, although the optimizer tends to transform this type of thing internally so it's hard to be sure.